# web forms: keep variables between requests

Tags: webforms

This is probably beginner's question, but if I need to keep variable's value between requests in web forms I have quite a bit of options:

- write hidden input element and carry value there
- keep value in Session dictionary
- keep value in ViewState dictionary
- probably something else I'm not aware of

So what is the right way in web forms? (I need to keep value between requests to the same page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx.  The MSDN articles list all the possible way you could save the state of you session.

If you just want to save the state of your controls between postback, you should use [ViewState](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what platform you're using, but usually sessions is the way to go. It means that only your code is able to alter that information, so you know what state it's in.

You can pass data in hidden fields in forms, but that means that the user may be able to change the data, and therefore you can't trust it. It also means that if the user navigates backwards and forwards, they may end up submitting stale data.

The only downside of sessions is that it requires cookies (which these days is normal) and the overhead of storing sessions.