# Login Attempts reset on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i am mostly a beginner at C# and now i'm doing an ATM program which will log the manager in, startup the system then the user can log in so they can view their balance and withdraw money from their account. However the problem i'm having is i want the label to say "Card Retained" when their attempts reach 5 but when i insert a breakpoint everytime the customer logs in the second time the attempts int is reset to 0 again. Hopefully this makes sense thanks in advance.

https://gyazo.com/0c6649df6abd88fc529c2cfafbe2cac9

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] within the question itself (rather than on an external site).

Answer (score 1):

For starters I'd advise against starting a new project in WebForms, given it's 2018.

Anyhow, variables reset with each request. You need to store the attempts somewhere more persistent, for example in a file on the server or in a database.

Yes, you could use viewstate as explained in [Best way to save variables between postbacks asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138480/best-way-to-save-variables-between-postbacks-asp-net) or sessions as explained in [web forms: keep variables between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791654/web-forms-keep-variables-between-requests), but then if the user removes their cookies or starts another browser, they have another five attempts.